# ElasticSearch term query vs query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch

When I query my index with query_string, I am getting results

But when I query using term query, I dont get any results

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "Printer.Name",
            "query": "HL-2230"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

I know that term is not_analyzed and query_string is analyzed but Name is already as "HL-2230", why doesnt it match with term query? I tried also searching with "hl-2230", I still didnt get any result.

[image]

EDIT: mapping looks like as below. Printer is the child of Product. Not sure if this makes difference

```
{
  "state": "open",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "creation_date": "1453816191454",
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "version": {
        "created": "1070199"
      },
      "uuid": "TfMJ4M0wQDedYSQuBz5BjQ"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "Product": {
      "properties": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": true,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "ProductName": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "Name": {
            "store": true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "ProductCode": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Number": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "store": true,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "id": {
        "index": "no",
        "store": true,
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "ShortDescription": {
        "store": true,
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Printer": {
        "_routing": {
          "required": true
        },
        "_parent": {
          "type": "Product"
        },
        "properties": {
          "properties": {
            "RelativeUrl": {
              "index": "no",
              "store": true,
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "PrinterId": {
          "index": "no",
          "store": true,
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "Name": {
          "store": true,
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "aliases": []
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the mapping of your `Printer.Name` field?

Comment: @Val Please see my edit. I added the mapping as well. Printer is basically child of Product. Could this be the problem or difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per mapping provided by you above

```
"Name": {
 "store": true,
 "type": "string"
 }
```

`Name` is analysed. So `HL-2230` will split into two tokens, `HL` and `2230`. That's why `term query` is not working and `query_string` is working. When you use `term query` it will search for exact term `HL-2230` which is not there.

Comment: does it mean that term query can be used only for not_analyzed fields?

Comment: No not necessarily, but only for searching the exact tokens as they have been indexed, in your case `hl` or `2230`

Comment: you are right. I have verified through the plugin with different cases and it works as you say it. thanks.